# Unable to get output from remote server

Tags: python, pexpect

```html
tcsh] jthimmai@musxoile24:~/jthimmai> cat monitor.py 

import pexpect, sys
child = pexpect.spawn ('ssh -l jthimmai musxoile24')
i = child.expect (['Terminal type', '[#\:] '])
if i==0:
    print'Login OK... need to send terminal type.'
    child.sendline('vt100')
    child.expect('[#\:] ')
elif i==1:
    print'Login OK.'
    print'Shell command prompt', child.after,child.before
    child.sendline('uname -a')
    #child.sendline('ls -lrt ')
    child.expect('[#\:]')
    print child.before
[Linux]                                                                                                                                                      [tcsh] jthimmai@musxoile24:~/jthimmai> 
tcsh] jthimmai@musxoile24:~/jthimmai> /opt/python_2.7.2/bin/python monitor.py
Login OK.
Shell command prompt :  Last login
Fri Mar 13 07
[Linux]                                                                                                                                                      [tcsh] jthimmai@musxoile24:~/jthimmai>
```

Comment: when commands (uname -a or ls -lrt)  sent to remote server .. expected output is not returned !

Answer (score 0):

If your "welcome message" is the same as mine, it has colons in it -- and you're looking for your prompt with a pattern that matches colons.

That's why `child.before` prints `Fri Mar 13 07` -- because the welcome message is something like:

```
Last login: Fri Mar 13 02:44:19 2015 from somehost.somedomain
                         ^
```

You could change your pattern inside your if statement to include a space (as you do previously)

```
prompt = '[#\:] '      # At the beginning, so you don't have to type it every time
#...

child.expect('[#\:]')  # This is inside your elif i==1 block
# to
child.expect(prompt)
```

Which should help.

Comment: no luck   getting   error  =====   raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().

Comment: @Jayanth can you update your code in your question to what you have currently?

Comment: it worked now .. prompts='[#\>] ' is the correct pattern